# Using Aggregate functions in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

My input file is below

```
a1,1,on,400 

a1,2,off,100

a1,3,on,200
```

I need to add $3 only if $2 is equal to "on".I have written script as below, after that I don't know how to proceed. For adding $3 only I need to apply some filter. for adding $1 there is no filter at all

Can someone help me on finishing this.

```
myinput = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(',') AS(id:chararray,flag:chararray,amt:int)
grouped = GROUP myinput BY id
```

I need output as below

a1, 6,600

Comment: search `FILTER` and `COUNT` [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#COUNT).  This should lead you to your answer.

Comment: Ok. I adjusted my input file by introducing a new atom in middle for each tuple.Can you help me now

Comment: Following up on GoBrewers14's comment, also look up nested `FOREACH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution,

You could do something like this (not tested) :

```
myinput = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(',');
A = FOREACH myinput GENERATE $0 as id, $1 as first_sum, (($2 == 'on') ? $3 : 0) as second_sum;
grouped = GROUP A BY id;
RESULT = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group as id, SUM($1.first_sum), SUM($1.second_sum);
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myinput = LOAD '/home/gopalkrishna/PIGPRAC/pig-sum.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray,num:int,stat:chararray,amt:int);


A = GROUP myinput BY name;

B = FOREACH A GENERATE group, SUM(myinput.num),SUM(myinput.amt);


STORE B INTO 'SUMOUT';
```